# Finding the initial velocity given angle and distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, velocity, projectile

I am trying to find the initial velocity of a projectile, only having been given the angle and the distance. I am to assume no incline and no air resistance. Which methods am I to use in order to get such results?

[image]

Comment: Show, at the very least, what you've tried?

Comment: @Gert The reason why I didn't include what I have tried is because while I have made myself familiar with situations in which time is known, I was not sure how to approach questions without including time.

Comment: @Frobenius I have removed the homework-and-exercises tag as it is not the case since I am trying to cover projectiles on my own.

Comment: @mkdirBed The tag is for homework-type questions, regardless whether they are really assigned homework or not.

Comment: @noah I see. My reasoning was that I was only wondering whether it was possible and not because I was working out an exercise, but thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to analyze the two axes separately. Let $x$ be the horizontal and $y$ be the vertical axis. The initial velocity for each axis is then

$$v_{0,x} = v_0 \cos\alpha \qquad \text{and} \qquad v_{0,y} = v_0 \sin\alpha$$

where $\alpha$ is the velocity vector angle measured anticlockwise from the positive $x$ axis to the vector.

In horizontal axis there is no acceleration, while in the vertical axis there is acceleration due to the gravity. The equations of motion for each axis are

$$x(t) - x_0 = \frac{1}{2} 0 t^2 + v_{0,x} t = v_{0,x} t \qquad \text{and} \qquad y(t) - y_0 = -\frac{1}{2} g t^2 + v_{0,y} t$$

where $x_0 = x(0)$ and $y_0 = y(0)$ is initial position, which in your case could be set to zero. There are two unknown variables in the above equations: time $t$ and initial velocity $v_0$. It does not take too much algebra to reach the final solution.